# AWS elastic transcoder batch transcoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, batch-processing, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Is it possible to transcode all .extensions in a bucket to an output bucket with one job? O r do I need to create a job for every single input file in a bucket using the api?

If I can use one job for all files in a bucket with a certain extension, how do I do that?  Or if there is some way to automate transcoding based on just uploading a file to a bucket, how do I do it?

Comment: Any solution you got?

Answer (score 1):

For automation I suggest to use AWS Lambda with AWS Elastic Transcoder, AWS Lamda can able to fetch files from source video S3 bucket and using Elastic transcoder can convert to mulitple profiles then put it on transcoded buckets.

Check here for more - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if you put in the *inputKey* in the request, a path thats apply to more than one file,(ej:"bucket/folder/A") amazon try to convert all the files with that key, in that case amazon will convert all the files in that folder when its name begin with an A.
But the problem is in the *outputKey*, because amazon try to save all the files in the same path(*OutputKey*), and throw an error. So I think you need to do a specific job for each file, or maybe, move each file before amazon try to save the next.

Answer (score 0):

No. Amazon S3 uses a flat file system. Each file is identified by a unique URI. You can write a utility which will pick up all files with a certain extension and submit those jobs to the transcoder separately